# How to repeat alarm using alarm manager (weekly or daily)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, alarmmanager

I am making a watering alarm for my application, I want it to alarm based on what I have set (weekly or daily) continuously. The problem is, it only alarm once and is not repeating

This is the switch statement for spinner where the user could choose if the alarm will be weekly or daily

```
switch (spinnerWF2){
                                        case "weekly":
                                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                            int currDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                                            scheduleAlarm(pName, currDay, time, 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                                            break;
                                        case "daily":
                                            Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                            int currDay2 = cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                                            scheduleAlarm(pName,currDay2,time, 24*60*60*1000);
                                            break;
                                    }
```

Method for scheduling alarm

```
private void scheduleAlarm(String text, int dayOfWeek ,long time, int intervalTime) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);

        // Check we aren't setting it in the past which would trigger it to fire instantly
        if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmBroadCastForTrack.class);
        // Set this to whatever you were planning to do at the given time
        intent.putExtra("message", text);
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        } else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        }

        String dateandtime = datePlanted.getText().toString() + " " + timeTonotify;
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d hh:mm");
        try {
            Date date1 = formatter.parse(dateandtime);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date1.getTime(),intervalTime, pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Setup Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

broadcast receiver for alarm

```
public class AlarmBroadCastForTrack extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String text = bundle.getString("message");
//        String de = bundle.getString("desc");
//        String date = bundle.getString("date") + " " + bundle.getString("time");

        //On receive on Notification
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, NotificationMessageForTrack.class);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent1.putExtra("message", text);
//        intent1.putExtra("desc", text);

        //Notification Builder
        PendingIntent pendingIntent ;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        } else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        }
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notify_001");

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout_for_track);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(androidx.appcompat.R.id.image, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent ;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        } else {
            pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        }
//        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.viewButton, pendingSwitchIntent);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.message, text);
//        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.description, de);
//        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.date, date);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_alarm_on_24);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
        mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        mBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
        mBuilder.build().flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH;
        mBuilder.setContent(contentView);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String channelId = "channel_id";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            mBuilder.setChannelId(channelId);
        }

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain, how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: i add firebase since I used it as a db of my project